# How to manage a very large number of IBOutlets in an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, interface-builder, iboutlet

I am trying to write an iPad app with the basic purpose of form filling. I have 5 independent forms that I have designed in Interface Builder with each form having more than 50 UILabels and UITextFields along with a few Segmented controls in a UIScrollView (yes, its a really really long form). These forms need to be locally saved in the app itself which can later be emailed. After designing the forms I realised that creating IBOutlets for such a large number of different controls is going to be tedious and might also hamper the performance of the app. I am also worried about the complexity it will create in managing these outlets.

I am not sure if I have taken the right approach. Can anybody suggest me any alternatives. I am ready to start everything from scratch, all I need is a little guidance towards the right approach to solve this problem. I only need help with managing the input elements, the rest I can manage.

Any and all suggestions are welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: there is something like this, @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UITextField) *myTFCollection;

Comment: You can just assign a different tag to each text field, and then store the value in it when textFielddidEndEditing: is called to the appropriate place, based on said tag. This only requires setting their delegates.

Comment: @inafziger, thanks, I think this might work, let me check. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama this might also work, but I'll have to try it first since I have never used OutletCollection before. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

*There can be two kinds of UILabels and UITextFields.*

*1. Static/Fixed text inside.*

*2. Dynamic text.*

*You create outlets for dynamic values that changes at runtime. Or if you are implementing some thing from codes.*

If you think 50 outlets are difficult to handle, you can **create 5 separate controller classes** for each `forms`, resulting in 10 outlets to handle in one controller class.

Comment: 50 is not the exact value, it could even be around 100. Anyways, I'll give a try to your suggested solution.

Comment: In osx applications one window may contain dozens of view. each view having 100s of outlets. So in the entire project 10windows*10views*100 outlets==10000 elements can be there. So just rethink the design and use **Divide and conquer rule**